# How do you access the model in an EditorFor template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do you access the model in an ASP.NET MVC Editor Template? For example if the parent view contains say:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Surname)
```

Then inside Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml we have:

```
@model String

<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x)
    @Model.Length
</div>
```

This fails at `@Model.Length` because `Model` is null, although the `LabelFor` and `TextBoxFor` render the correct Surname properties.

When `Html.DisplayFor` with the equivalent template file is used, `Model` does contain the given string value.

Comment: not sure what your question is. Why not add a `@if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Model))` check?

Comment: It's not a question of checking for null, `Model` is always null, even though `Surname` has a value, and its value and name are correctly displayed by `TextBoxFor` and `LabelFor`.

Comment: what happens when you put a breakpoint at `@Model.Length`? Are you sure it's not firing from some other `EditorFor(x => x.String)?`

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you don't have other `string` properties in your view which might be null?

Comment: Ah you're right, scrap all that, the error wasn't in the instance of the template I thought it was. Sorry! Thanks for you help @DLeh, Stephen.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Editor Template for something as broad as `String` could have unintended consequences, since you will very likely have many `EditorFor(x => x.StringValue)`s in your code that you *don't* want this Editor Template to apply to.

It's likely that you have another `EditorFor` that is causing the nullref exception here.